# Linearity of the Dirac delta function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

It is known that the Dirac delta function is linear. I do not understand why Mathematica says that `a DiracDelta[x] + b DiracDelta[x]` is not equal to `(a + b) DiracDelta[x]`, assuming `a` and `b` are real numbers larger than zero.

Comment: Try Collect[a*DiracDelta[x] + b*DiracDelta[x], DiracDelta[x]]. There are more serious problems with DiracDelta in Mathematica.

Comment: `Integrate[(a DiracDelta[x] + 
    b DiracDelta[x] - (a + b) DiracDelta[x]) \[Phi][
   x], {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]` returns `0`, though.

Comment: `a DiracDelta[x] + b DiracDelta[x] // Factor` works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression

```
a DiracDelta[x] + b DiracDelta[x] == (a + b) DiracDelta[x]
```

is a tautology — basically just a statement of the distributive law of ordinary arthmetic. It is true for any function `f`, linear on not.

```
Reduce[a f[x] + b f[x] == (a + b) f[x]]
```

> `True`

Comment: That is great! Thank you very much!

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, **[accept the answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)** that you found most helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/77809)